# Multidimensional arrays ( Index was outside the bounds of the array.)

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to make an array with 300 numbers, I want to add negative numbers in the array but I don't know how. I tried this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int t= 250;
        int[]num = new int[t];
        int i;
        int j=0;
        int pos=0,neg=0,szero=0;

        for(i=-50;i<t;i++)
        {
            num[j]= i;
            j++;
        }

        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            if (j==0)
                szero++;
            if (j>0)
                pos++;
            if (j<0)
                neg++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int t= 250;
int[]num = new int[t];
```

This creates an array with 250 'slots' in it. Each slot can contain an integer; so far so good.

```
for(i=-50;i<t;i++)
{
    num[j]= i;
    j++;
}
```

Think about what you're trying to do here: You're looping over i, from -50 to 250, and adding 1 each time. That'll be 300 iterations of the loop. If your array has 250 slots, how can you fit 300 numbers in it? You can't; when your code reaches the 251st iteration of the loop, j will be equal to 250, and will be outside the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 0):

the counter with negative values must be defined outside the for loop not as the main for counter variable.